# DynamoDB - Create a table of many-to-many mapping

Tags: primary-key, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to create a DynamoDB that stores a many-to-many mapping. Let's say I have two attributes:

```
Genre
Author
```

Suppose I am chiefly using this mapping to look for Author by Genre, then it makes sense to have Genre as hash key and Author by range key. However, suppose I want to search Genre by Author as well, then how should I make this happen? Introduce a global secondary key with Author as hash key and Genre as range key?

Thanks

Comment: It makes sense to me to introduce a GSI where `Author` is the hash key, and `Genre` is the range key. How many different types of genres are you going to have?

Comment: So that's probably the best way for this purpose? We can assume Genre and Author both have cardinality.

Comment: Yup, a GSI should work perfectly fine for that key structure.